# Android after getting user's contacts into a list, Can't use them

Tags: java, android, android-cursoradapter, contactscontract

I've manged to use the following code for retrieving user's contacts into a list, and now I'm working on the next step (getting individual info of each contact):

```
package com.example.mycontacts;

import android.app.LoaderManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.CursorLoader;
import android.content.Loader;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;

/**
 * Created by daniel on 28/02/2016.
 */
public class ContactListFragment  extends ListFragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    private CursorAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        // create adapter once
        Context context = getActivity();
        int layout = android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1;
        Cursor c = null; // there is no cursor yet
        int flags = 0; // no auto-requery! Loader requeries.
        mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(context, layout, c, FROM, TO, flags);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        // each time we are started use our listadapter
        setListAdapter(mAdapter);
        // and tell loader manager to start loading
        getActivity().getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, (android.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>) this);
    }

    // columns requested from the database
    private static final String[] PROJECTION = {
            ContactsContract.Contacts._ID, // _ID is always required
            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY // that's what we want to display
    };

    // and name should be displayed in the text1 textview in item layout
    private static final String[] FROM = { ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY };
    private static final int[] TO = { android.R.id.text1 };

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {

        // load from the "Contacts table"
        Uri contentUri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;

        // no sub-selection, no sort order, simply every row
        // projection says we want just the _id and the name column
        return new CursorLoader(getActivity(),
                contentUri,
                PROJECTION,
                null,
                null,
                null);
    }



    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        // Once cursor is loaded, give it to adapter
        mAdapter.swapCursor(data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        // on reset take any old cursor away
        mAdapter.swapCursor(null);
    }
}
```

The problem is, I can't find a way to get the info from each contact, in the onItemClick() of the list.
Any idea?

**EDIT**
I actually added:

```
ListView newsList = new ListView(getActivity());
    newsList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        }
    });
```

but didn't know how to proceed and how interact with cursor.

**EDIT2**

I changed it from listfragment to dialogFragment with a listview, but still I don't get the contact's number by pressing on the item (in list).
what am I misiing here?

```
> package com.example...;

import android.app.LoaderManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.CursorLoader;
import android.content.Loader;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Created by daniel on 28/02/2016.
 */
public class DialogFragment extends android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
    private TextView dateView;
    private Spinner actionSpinner;
    private Button okButton;
    private CursorAdapter mAdapter;
    private TimePicker timePicker;
    private static final String[] FROM = { ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY };
    private static final int[] TO = { android.R.id.text1 };
    private ListView list;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog,container,false);


        Context context = getActivity();
        int layout = android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1;
        Cursor c = null; // there is no cursor yet
        int flags = 0; // no auto-requery! Loader requeries.
        mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(context, layout, c, FROM, TO, flags);

        actionSpinner = (Spinner)v.findViewById(R.id.actionSpinner);
        okButton = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.saveButton);
        list = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.listView);




        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(),
        R.array.actions, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        actionSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        okButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getDialog().dismiss();
                Comm comm = (Comm) getActivity();
                comm.pick();
            }
        });

        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                mAdapter.getItem(position);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), String.valueOf(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });





        return v;
    }


    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);


        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        list.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        // and tell loader manager to start loading
        getActivity().getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, (android.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>) this);
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {

        // load from the "Contacts table"
        Uri contentUri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;

        // no sub-selection, no sort order, simply every row
        // projection says we want just the _id and the name column
        return new CursorLoader(getActivity(),
                contentUri,
                PROJECTION,
                null,
                null,
                null);    }

    private static final String[] PROJECTION = {
            ContactsContract.Contacts._ID, // _ID is always required
            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY // that's what we want to display
    };

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        mAdapter.swapCursor(data);

    }



    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        mAdapter.swapCursor(null);

    }


}
```

Comment: *I can't find a way to get the info from each contact, in the onItemClick() of the list* from code it seems like you didn't even tried... obviously you have to obtain cursor in onItemClick (asked bazillion times) then get data from cursor(asked even more than bazillion times) ... unfortunatly your cursor has only 2 columns, if you need more you should obviously modify PROJECTION

Comment: where? there is no overrided onItemclick of ListFragment neither you didn't setup the LitView listener ...

Comment: you are creating new ListView instance and setting listener to it ... you shuold read how to use ListFragment ... http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html#onListItemClick(android.widget.ListView,%20android.view.View,%20int,%20long) => ((Cursor)l.getItemAtPosition(position))

Comment: Basically what I'm trying to do is, when I click on the contact name, I'll get the phone number